# How do I show a special symbol at the beginning of show lines (which are in the middle of logical lines) when wrap is on?

Tags: wrapping, listchars

The screenshot of `vim-gitgutter` clearly shows its author uses some kind of continuation line character when `wrap` is on. How do I get that? I thought I could find it listed in `:help 'listchars'`, but it's not.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `'showbreak'` option. From [`:h 'showbreak'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27showbreak%27):

> ```
> 'showbreak' 'sbr'      string (default "")
>                        global or local to window |global-local|
>
>        String to put at the start of lines that have been wrapped.
> ```

---

It looks to me like they are using the Unicode character ↪ ([Rightwards Arrow with Hook, U+21AA](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+21AA)). To enter a Unicode character into Vim, use [`:h i_CTRL-V`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL%2DV).

After typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, you can hit <kbd>u</kbd> and type the hexadecimal representation of the desired Unicode character (as specified in [`:h i_CTRL-V_digit`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL%2DV_digit)).

So, to type ↪, you would perform the following keypresses while in insert or command-line mode:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

---

Then, you can `set showbreak=↪` in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: It's a bit strange it has an option for its own and isn't part of `listchars`.

Comment: @jake-grossman Nailed it :) https://github.com/airblade/dotvim/blob/763b6c73bef1e69487d1e53d8dd80f4c257feb13/vimrc#L108-L109